# How to create a unique index for a subset of rows in a db2 table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to create a unique index for a subset of data in a particular table. The existing data is something like this -

[image]

But the actual data should look like this -

[image]

The subset of rows will be the rows with the condition status as A or B. For these set of rows, the unique_id and amount value combination should be unique.

The DB2 version been used here is 9.7 on a windows server. Is partial index or conditional index possible in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

## New table

```
create or replace function generate_unique_det()
returns varchar(13) for bit data
deterministic
no external action
contains sql
return generate_unique();

create table test_unique (
  unique_id int not null
, status char(1) not null
, amount int not null
, status2 varchar(13) for bit data not null generated always as 
  (case when status in ('A', 'B') then '' else generate_unique_det() end)
) in userspace1;

create unique index test_unique1 on test_unique (unique_id, amount, status2);

insert into test_unique (unique_id, status, amount) 
values
  (1234, 'A', 400)
--, (1234, 'B', 400)
, (1234, 'Z', 400)
, (1234, 'Z', 400);
```

The standard `generate_unique` function is not deterministic.
Such functions are not allowed in the `generated always` clause.
This is why we create our own function based on the standard one.
The problem with such a "fake" function could be, if Db2 not actually called this function for each updated / inserted row during a multi-row change operation (why to call the `deterministic` function multiple times on the same set of parameters, if it's enough to do it once and reuse the result for other affected rows afterwards). But it works in reality - Db2 does call such a function for every affected row, which is desired in our case.
You are not able to insert the commented out row in the last statement.

## Existing table

```
set integrity for test_unique off;

alter table test_unique add 
status2 varchar(13) for bit data not null 
generated always as (case when status in ('A', 'B') then '' else generate_unique_det() end);

set integrity for test_unique immediate checked force generated;

-- If you need to save the rows violated future unique index
create table test_unique_exc like test_unique in userspace1;

-- If you don't need to save the the rows violated future unique index,  
-- then just run the inner DELETE statement only,
-- which just removes these rows.
-- The whole statement inserts the deleted rows into the "exception table".
with d as (
  select unique_id, status, amount, status2
  from old table (
    delete from (select t.*, rownumber() over (partition by unique_id, amount, status2) rn_ from test_unique t) where rn_>1
  )
)
select count(1)
from new table (
  insert into test_unique_exc select * from d
);

create unique index test_unique1 on test_unique (unique_id, amount, status2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. What if the test_unique is an existing table with some 50,000 rows? I can alter the existing table by adding a new column status2 with the condition or bit data not null generated always as 
  (case when status in ('A', 'B') then '' else generate_unique_det() end) ?

Comment: @Manoj The solution for an existing table added.